# node http get function works only a few times

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I am new to node, so please bear with me. I'm trying to write a function that tests to make sure there is a live connection to the web server before redirecting the page.

This works for the first 6 - 7 clicks, then the page will not redirect anymore - it just sits there. Then a few minutes later, an alert will show.

What is going on?!

```
var http = require("http");
var url = 'http://example.com/';

mainMenu.click(function () {
  var menulink = $(this).attr('rel');
  var menuvar = http.get(url, function () {
    window.location = menulink;
  }).on('error', function () {
    alert('Cannot Connect to Server');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have a problem with [non-flowing streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

Since you never consume the data of your responses, the connection never closes. The [HTTP Agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) limits the number of concurrent connections and refuses to open any new connection after a while.

You should try to manually switch the response to flowing mode:

```
mainMenu.click(function () {
  var menulink = $(this).attr('rel');
  var menuvar = http.get(url, function (res) {
    // FORCE FLOWING MODE
    res.resume();
    window.location = menulink;
  }).on('error', function () {
    alert('Cannot Connect to Server');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That took care of it. Is this the best method to deal with this? Is there a way to close the connection?

Comment: That's the best method: it will consume all the data and let the server will close the response.